# Why is it called "Matzah shmurah"?

Tags: hebrew, matzah

The term "מצה שמורה", means "watched matzah". AFAIK, in making "shmurah matzot" The **wheat** is being watched, not the matzah, itself. Perhaps, from the time it comes out of the oven until it's packaged, it's watched, but, then again, so are "non shmurah" matzot, and I don't think that's what the term applies to, anyway.

So why not call it מצה מתבואה שמורה or something similar.

**Note** I used the term תבואה because nowadays, matzot are also commonly made from oats and spelt, and not just wheat.

Comment: שמורה means guarded not watched.

Comment: Maybe they call it that because all the longer more precise versions you can think of are...longer?

Comment: @DoubleAA agreed, the other versions are longer. However, brevity doesn't always = preciseness.

Comment: Rarely does it, in fact. If in the interest of precision you'd like to start saying an entire paragraph when you want someone to pass you the Shmura Matza and end up with them being confused, be my guest.

Comment: @DoubleAA sarcastic but funny ;-)

Comment: I always assumed it was just accepted, not accurate. Similarly, "18-minute Matzah" is understood to be Matzah where the entire machinery is changed every 18 minutes - though nothing in the name would indicate that.

Comment: I don't think @DoubleAA is being sarcastic (correct me if I'm wrong). Shmurah matzah is concise and people know what it means. Nobody is trying to make diyukim from the name.

Answer (score 1):

Normal matza is "watched completely from grinding to baking" -- yes, at the baking stage it's matza, at the grinding stage it's "flour." So we refer to extra-shmurah as "matza that was watched completely, from harvesting to baking."

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: מַּצָּה שְׁמוּרָה - matzva that was guarded from "inception".

Answer (score -1):

Shmura ("guarded") matzah (Hebrew מַצָּה שְׁמוּרָה maṣṣā šəmūrā) is made from grain that has been under special supervision from the time it was harvested to ensure that no fermentation has occurred, and that it is suitable for eating on the first night of Passover.

Comment: This answer seems to just confirm what my premise is. It doesn't answer the reason for the terminology.

Comment: so are you saying, it should be just called מצה עשויה מתבואה משומרת or something like that?

Comment: yes - though, see my answer, below. Granted, now that I think it over, I should make this a different question, rather than an answer to this one.